# Passing application to AndroidViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to use [AndroidViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel.html) for my view model in order to get access to the `Context`. It requires `Application` to be passed as a parameter. My ViewModel class looks like this:

```
class FooAndroidViewModel(application: Application?) : AndroidViewModel(aplication) {
  ...
}
```

It is getting instantiated like this:

```
val fooModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FooAndroidViewModel::class.java)
```

The problem is that this gives an error, that `FooAndroidViewModel` cannot be instantiated - probably because of the missing `application` parameter.

---

**Question:** how to pass `application` to `ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FooAndroidViewModel::class.java)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just replace `application: Application?` to `application: Application`. Following code should work:

```
class FooAndroidViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
  // class def
}
```

Comment: Hmm, actually just figured out, that it works both way.

Comment: @Oleg, do you recall what the issue was? I'm facing a similar problem and my code is exactly as it is in this answer.

Comment: Fixed by retrieving the view model via `by viewModels()`. I was retrieving it in the fragment's `onCreate()` previously, which is apparently a no-go.

Answer (score 2):

Even if we have it this way,

```
class FooAndroidViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(aplication)
```

But we don't go with `by viewModels()` option and instead try to use this as,

```
val mViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(FooAndroidViewModel::class.java)
```

Then it gives an exception,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class x.y.z.FooAndroidViewModel

Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<x.y.z.FooAndroidViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
```

I solved it by creating instance of `AndroidViewModel` this way,

```
val mViewModel = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(application).create(FooAndroidViewModel::class.java)
```