# unable to context in ViewModel

Tags: java, android, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I am new to android and trying to implement MVVM for first time .

I am building application to get access all folders having video stored in user mobile for that I need to use cursor .

main problem is how to use cursor without using context in ViewModel.
and context this MainActivity.this or getApplicationContext() is not working.

i have to pass context in getAllFolder();

(i have also read in stack that using context in viewmodel is not good approach)

[image]

thank you for your help.

Comment: I need to undestand well. do you mean that the way you are using Context now is not working or you just need to improve it by avoid using context in your viewModel?

Comment: No it is not working.. in order to work it I need to pass it inside function

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/56490520/7707187