# Custom colors of TextView are different than Android Studio shows

Tags: android, xml, colors, textview, color-palette

I have a problem with incorrect TextView colors. I'm using this expression in xml fragment:

```
android:textColor="@{viewModel.currentColorOfText}"
```

In ViewModel I use
When I'm using `currentColorOfText = Color.BLUE` everything is okay but when I switch to color defined by myself:

`currentColorOfText.value = R.color.blue`

TextView is **gray** (should be blue :))

My defined color in color.xml:

```
<color name="blue">#0010FF</color>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching a Color Resource ID not a Color value.

If you open the Colors File you will see that `Color.BLUE` is a int value:

`@ColorInt public static final int BLUE        = 0xFF0000FF;`

To use your Resource Color you will need to pass the context of you Activity/Application([Link to understand which one you should pass](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-context-in-android-application-330913e32514)).

Then use the below line of code:

`currentColorOfText.value = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.blue)`

Check Out the [StackOverflow answer on how to pass context.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51451819/how-to-get-context-in-android-mvvm-viewmodel)

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot. Is using getApplication() as context is proper approach?