# Kotlin Composable ViewModel Hoisting - Context

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, hoisting, composable

I'm transitioning from iOS SWIFT to Android Kotlin & Jetpack, and struggling a little with @composables, I'm not using activity/fragments. I'm creating separate ViewModel classes to hoist state & business logic but I'm struggling with context.

Within the ViewModel's there's a number of functions that require context, example registerReceiver, I'm also using a number of libraries such as MQTT client. From my research I shouldn't be using context in a ViewModel:

[How to get Context in Android MVVM ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51451819/how-to-get-context-in-android-mvvm-viewmodel)

So my question is how do create ViewModel that requires context for dependent functions, or is my understanding of context or ViewModel wrong?

I know it's not recommended but for a few features I've created functions in the ViewModel which the composable calls and pass context = LocalContext.current

As an example within the ViewModel I've created the following:

```
fun registerScannerReceiver(context: Context) {
        val filter = IntentFilter(context.getString(R.string.datawedge_intent_filter_action))
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
        context.registerReceiver(reciver, filter)
    }
```

This works but it feels wrong any suggestions, recommendations or example code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel Use this and get the context from the Application. Application is effectively a singleton and cannot be leaked so it’s safe for the ViewModel to hold a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

You should never pass a `Context` from a `Composable` to a `ViewModel`.  The `ViewModel` could outlive the `Composable`, resulting in a memory leak or an app crash.  Here is [the direct quote from the Android Team](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel):

> Caution: A ViewModel usually shouldn't reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context. Because the ViewModel lifecycle is larger than the UI's, holding a lifecycle-related API in the ViewModel could cause memory leaks.

There are several other ways you can solve it:

1. If your `Composable` will only interact with one `ViewModel`, try passing the `ViewModel` as an argument to it from the higher level `Composable`.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SubComponent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: MyViewModel,
) {...}
```

2. If you're working with a `Composable` that supports multiple other `ViewModels`, you could pass an `Application` variable.  Any context derived from the `Application` will have longer lifecycle, resulting in fewer crashes.  I don't recommend this option, as it will still leak a `Context` object.

```kotlin
class MyViewModel(private val application: Application) : ViewModel() {
private val leakyContext = application.applicationContext as Context
...
}
```

3. Don't use a ViewModel to build `Intent`. Separate it to a utility type class, so you can reuse it across your application. Call your newly created class from the `Composable`

```kotlin
class Util {
fun callIntent(context: Context, actionString: String) {
        val filter = IntentFilter(actionString)
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
        context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
        ...
    }
...
}

@Composable
fun SubComponent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: MyViewModel,
    util: Util = Util()
) {
private val context = LocalContext.current
util.callIntent(context,context.getString(R.string.datawedge_intent_filter_action))
...
}
```

I hope this helps explain the issues.

Comment: Robert thank you so much for your detailed reply it's helped a lot and I've refactored my application and it does feel better and cleaner.